# Use a TR as a form submit button rather than a button that says edit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, onclick

I have a PHP page that generates a list of truck loads and I want to get rid of the Edit button and instead make it so when you click on the TR it submits the form for edit.

**So far I have found an option similer that submits to a specified URL.** This code will let you click on the TR and it will take you to the URL posted in the tr onclick

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function DoNav(theUrl)
{
document.location.href = theUrl;
}
</script>

<table width="100%" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
   <tr onclick="DoNav('http://www.google.com/');">
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

**Here is my current code.**

```
echo str_repeat("<form action=\"process.php\" method=\"post\">

    <tr>
    <td><input type=\"submit\" name=\"edit\" value=\"Edit\"></td>

    <td>" . ($row['1']) . "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"date_added\" id=\"date_added\" readonly style=\"border: none;border-color: transparent;text-align: center;\" value=\"" . ($row['1']) . "\"></td>
    <td>" . ($row['2']) . "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"carrier\" id=\"carrier\" readonly style=\"border: none;border-color: transparent;text-align: center;\" value=\"" . ($row['2']) . "\"></td>
    <td>" . ($row['3']) . "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"trailer\" id=\"trailer\" readonly style=\"border: none;border-color: transparent;text-align: center;\" value=\"" . ($row['3']) . "\"></td>
    <td>" . ($row['4']) . "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"door_number\" id=\"door_number\" readonly style=\"border: none;border-color: transparent;text-align: center;\" value=\"" . ($row['4']) . "\"></td>
    <td>" . ($row['5']) . "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"time_in\" id=\"time_in\" readonly style=\"border: none;border-color: transparent;text-align: center;\" value=\"" . ($row['5']) . "\"></td>
    <td>" . ($row['6']) . "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"time_out\" id=\"time_out\" readonly style=\"border: none;border-color: transparent;text-align: center;\" value=\"" . ($row['6']) . "\"></td>
    <td>" . ($row['7']) . "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"po_number\" id=\"po_number\" readonly style=\"border: none;border-color: transparent;text-align: center;\" value=\"" . ($row['7']) . "\"></td>
    <td>" . ($row['8']) . "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"update_notes\" id=\"update_notes\" rows=\"1\" cols=\"30\" readonly style=\"text-align: justify;\" value=\"\">" . ($row['8']) . "</textarea></td>

    </tr></form>",1);
```

**Currently my site looks like this.**

```
─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
|    |DATE      |CARRIER|TRAILER #|DOOR #|TIME IN |TIME OUT|P.O. #    |NOTES|
|Edit|2017-10-27|England|18410    |26    |18:15:59|20:34:27|4555894722|     |
|Edit|2017-10-25|England|25688    |18    |10:13:45|16:37:01|4555821145|     |
|Edit|2017-10-24|Central|581324   |35    |05:38:45|12:37:21|4555874774|     |
─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
```

**I want to get rid of the Edit button and instead have the whole TR be the Edit button.**

```
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
|DATE      |CARRIER|TRAILER #|DOOR #|TIME IN |TIME OUT|P.O. #    |NOTES|
|2017-10-27|England|18410    |26    |18:15:59|20:34:27|4555894722|     |
|2017-10-25|England|25688    |18    |10:13:45|16:37:01|4555821145|     |
|2017-10-24|Central|581324   |35    |05:38:45|12:37:21|4555874774|     |
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
```

Comment: What is the problem and question?

Comment: `document.location.href = theUrl;` thats not submitting the form

Comment: You want to use Ajax for something like that. Then you'll basicly have a click event on the table row that will trigger a function that turns the table fields into editable fields and use custom blur or focus events on those that will trigger the Ajax function to perform the update on that specific field.

Comment: @icecub When the TR is clicked I just want it to take me to the process page where I can edit the row by it self. Because of the way it will be used it will be better to have it edited on a different page.

Comment: So give the table row a class and a unique id. Create a custom javascript event that will trigger on clicking on the class and retrieve the specific id via `this`. Then redirect towards the edit page using the id for the correct data